# Django: Write a Create/Update template for a model with a ManyToMany-Through relationship

Tags: django, django-models

In my app I have users, and each user can speak several languages, each at a different level. So this is how I wrote my models:

```py
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='SpeakingLevel')

class SpeakingLevel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)

    LEVEL_OK = 1
    LEVEL_BAD = 2
    LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        (1, "Ok"),
        (2, "Bad")
    )
    level = models.IntegerField(null=True,
                                choices=LEVEL_CHOICES)
```

My doubt is how should I write the templates for the UserProfile creation/updating. I have no idea. The idea is having something like this (it's an screenshot from okcupid.com):

[image]

Of course, I can do it manually with a lot of javascript, and maybe a javascript template engine to add new languages to the list, but it sounds crazy for just handling a relationship, I'm sure I'm missing some cool Django feature to handle this.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Basically, you would create an inline formset for your `SpeakingLevel` model and attach it to your `UserProfile` form. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). I think this will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: The inline formset plus [django-formset-js](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-formset-js/) did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This solution is apply when You create the UserProfile in django admin panel.

Django has something like [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines), but the problem with this is that the section with languages will not be visible while You create UserProfile, after You create that and go to the edit view, then You will see inline with languages.

Inline already has all required javascript code :)

PS. If You find some other 'cool' solution let me know in comment, I'm curious :)

Comment: I finally used an inline formset and [django-formset-js](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-formset-js/), a cool jquery plugin to handle django formsets.